Merging env JSON files for newman run
In my project, we are maintaining multiple JSON files for each post request of collection.Request wise, we need to maintain like this for keeping environment variables. We will do run via new man.
My requirement is to want to merge all environment json files and make it as single file. Then,get it executed with source(collection file)
Is any way to merge files via any cmd comment and any method

This demo.js can merge multiple environment variable files
The merged JSON file ('demo.postman_environment.json')
copy first JSON's attributes (id, name, _postman_variable_scope, _postman_exported_at and _postman_exported_using)
from the 2nd to the nth JSON just copy Key/value pair into merged JSON file.

const fs = require('fs');

// Function to merge multiple JSON objects
function mergeJSONObjects(jsonObjects) {
    const baseJSON = jsonObjects[0]; // Use the first JSON as the base structure

    // Loop over remaining JSON objects and merge their 'values' arrays into the base JSON
    jsonObjects.slice(1).forEach(json => {
        baseJSON.values = [...baseJSON.values, ...json.values];
    });

    return baseJSON;
}

// Read JSON data from files specified in command-line arguments
const jsonFiles = process.argv.slice(2); // Skip the first two args (node and script name)
const jsonObjects = jsonFiles.map(file => JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8')));

// Perform the merge
const mergedJSON = mergeJSONObjects(jsonObjects);

// Output the merged JSON
console.log(JSON.stringify(mergedJSON, null, 4));

// Optionally, save the merged JSON to a file
fs.writeFileSync('demo.postman_environment.json', JSON.stringify(mergedJSON, null, 4), 'utf8');

Run it with file names argurement
node demo.js first.json second.json third.json

Result
demo.postman_environment.json

example
demo1.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "efdf42ef-3df9-45cb-a6a7-b8f8a40b2712",
    "name": "demo1",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "Animal1",
            "value": "Lion",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-04-27T16:26:09.645Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.24.24"
}

demo2.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "d85b8da5-2a00-4daa-beba-ba00f55b46b1",
    "name": "demo2",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "Animal2",
            "value": "Elephant",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-04-27T16:26:29.585Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.24.24"
}

demo3.postman_environment.json
{
    "id": "59fe0bfa-5071-4108-987e-e30a0345af69",
    "name": "demo3",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "Animal3",
            "value": "Tiger",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-04-27T16:26:58.829Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.24.24"
}

Result
{
    "id": "efdf42ef-3df9-45cb-a6a7-b8f8a40b2712",
    "name": "demo1",
    "values": [
        {
            "key": "Animal1",
            "value": "Lion",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "Animal2",
            "value": "Elephant",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        },
        {
            "key": "Animal3",
            "value": "Tiger",
            "type": "default",
            "enabled": true
        }
    ],
    "_postman_variable_scope": "environment",
    "_postman_exported_at": "2024-04-27T16:26:09.645Z",
    "_postman_exported_using": "Postman/10.24.24"
}

Test merged JSON with collection

1-demo.postman_collection.json
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "7fab6ad2-98f1-429e-9943-fac7f5b9e491",
        "name": "1-demo",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json",
        "_exporter_id": "1826150"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Get Tiger",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal Name = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Lion\");\r",
                            "});\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{Animal1}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "{{Animal1}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get Elephant",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal Name = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Elephant\");\r",
                            "});\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{Animal2}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "{{Animal2}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
        {
            "name": "Get Tiger",
            "event": [
                {
                    "listen": "prerequest",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "listen": "test",
                    "script": {
                        "exec": [
                            "const jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);\r",
                            "console.log(jsonData[0].name);\r",
                            "pm.test('Animal Name = ' + jsonData[0].name, function () {\r",
                            "    pm.expect(jsonData[0].name).to.eql(\"Tiger\");\r",
                            "});\r",
                            ""
                        ],
                        "type": "text/javascript",
                        "packages": {}
                    }
                }
            ],
            "request": {
                "auth": {
                    "type": "noauth"
                },
                "method": "GET",
                "header": [],
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://freetestapi.com/api/v1/animals?search={{Animal3}}",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "freetestapi",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1",
                        "animals"
                    ],
                    "query": [
                        {
                            "key": "search",
                            "value": "{{Animal3}}"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "event": [
        {
            "listen": "prerequest",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "listen": "test",
            "script": {
                "type": "text/javascript",
                "exec": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "variable": [
        {
            "key": "priductIds",
            "value": "[\"1001\", \"1002\", \"1003\", \"1004\", \"3002\"]",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "priductId",
            "value": "1001",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "baseUrl",
            "value": "https://valentinos-coffee.herokuapp.com",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "key": "AnimalItemLength",
            "value": ""
        }
    ]
}

newman run
newman run 1-demo.postman_collection.json -e demo.postman_environment.json



You up vote also give 10 more points, can you give me up vote too?
